# How to obtain multiple statistics of different variables under a certain group?

Tags: r

I have 3 different groups of cars (`origin`: 1, 2, and 3, which are American, European, and Japanese respectively). I also have multiple variables such as `mpg`, `displacement`, `horsepower`, `weight`, and `acceleration`. I would like to write a code in which I could get the mean and standard deviation of these 5 variables only for the American cars (`origin == 1`).

I am using the `tapply()` command but that requires 10 different entries and it doesn't filter out the type 2 and 3 cars.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using a modified subset of the `mtcars` data set with a `group` column added. Starting with

```
> dat
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb group
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     1
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     1
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     2
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     2
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     3
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     3
```

To calculate the mean and standard deviation for all columns for cars in group 1, you can use `sapply` with an anonymous function:

```
> sapply(dat[dat$group == 1, -length(dat)], function(x) {
             c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)) 
  })
#      mpg cyl disp  hp drat        wt       qsec vs am gear carb 
# mean  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.7475000 16.7400000  0  1    4    4 
# sd     0   0    0   0  0.0 0.1803122  0.3959798  0  0    0    0
```

If you want only a few columns calculated, subset by group and columns (here I use `mpg`, `hp`, and `wt`) and then use `sapply` as above

```
> d <- dat[dat$group == 1, c("mpg", "hp", "wt")]
> sapply(d, function(x) {
      c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  })
#      mpg  hp        wt
# mean  21 110 2.7475000
# sd     0   0 0.1803122
```

Or, you can use this `easyStats` function I wrote and get a few more simple statistics.

```
> easyStats <- function(x, digits = 3L, ...)
  {
      stopifnot(as.logical(length(x)), is.vector(x), is.numeric(x))
      funs <- c("mean", "median", "sd", "max", "min")
      mp <- mapply(function(f, ...) match.fun(f)(x, ...), funs, ...)
      round(mp, digits = digits)
  }
> sapply(dat[dat$group == 1, -length(dat)], easyStats, na.rm = TRUE)
#        mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt   qsec vs am gear carb
# mean    21   6  160 110  3.9 2.748 16.740  0  1    4    4     
# median  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.748 16.740  0  1    4    4     
# sd       0   0    0   0  0.0 0.180  0.396  0  0    0    0     
# max     21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.020  0  1    4    4     
# min     21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.460  0  1    4    4
```

**Data:**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1), cyl = c(6, 
6, 4, 6, 8, 6), disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225), hp = c(110, 
110, 93, 110, 175, 105), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 
2.76), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46), qsec = c(16.46, 
17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
    am = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), gear = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3), carb = c(4, 
    4, 1, 1, 2, 1), group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)), .Names = c("mpg", 
"cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", 
"carb", "group"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is is great!! The only problem now is that some of the variables have some "NA" values, so is not calculating the results.  I know I could use "na.rm = TRUE"... but it is not working...

Comment: I'm new with R so this actually resolved a lot of my doubts.  Thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and welcome to R!  It's a great language.

Answer (score 0):

Using mtcars as data and gear as group:

```
> colMeans(mtcars[mtcars$gear==3,], na.rm=T)
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
 16.106667   7.466667 326.300000 176.133333   3.132667   3.892600  17.692000   0.200000   0.000000   3.000000   2.666667 
> 
> apply(mtcars[mtcars$gear==3,], 2, function(x)sd(x,na.rm=T))
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
 3.3716182  1.1872337 94.8527355 47.6892720  0.2736647  0.8329929  1.3499164  0.4140393  0.0000000  0.0000000  1.1751393
```

Can be simplified to (as suggested by   Richard Scriven ):

```
> apply(mtcars[mtcars$gear==3,], 2, sd, na.rm=T)
       mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
 3.3716182  1.1872337 94.8527355 47.6892720  0.2736647  0.8329929  1.3499164  0.4140393  0.0000000  0.0000000  1.1751393
```

Comment: This also works, I was actually told that the "colMeans" and "Apply" commands would work for this problem, but I still have problems setting "na.rm=TRUE" in the code

Comment: @rnso -  you can still pass `na.rm = TRUE` to `sd` the way I suggested with  `apply(data, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks again for the tip. I am editing my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As my friends above, I'll use the `mtcars` dataset. It doesn't have a "country of origin" variable, but I'll use `cyl` instead, because it also has three levels. Say american cars are equivalente to 4 cilinders.

First of all, let's create a filtered dataset. It is better to do this just once instead of having R refilter your original dataset every time you run `aggregate`:

```
american <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, ]
```

Now, let's first calculate the mean of several variables:

```
aggregate(formula = cbind(mpg, hp, drat, wt, qsec) ~ cyl,
          data    = american,
          FUN     = mean)
```

Now the standard deviation:

```
aggregate(formula = cbind(mpg, hp, drat, wt, qsec) ~ cyl,
          data    = american,
          FUN     = sd)
```

Hope that helps.